# Activation function for neural network

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, neural-network, classification

I need help in figuring out a suitable activation function. Im training my neural network to detect a piano note. So in this case I can have only one output. Either the note is there (1) or the note is not present (0).
Say I introduce a threshold value of 0.5 and say that if the output is greater than 0.5 the desired note is present and if its less than 0.5 the note isn't present, what type of activation function can I use. I assume it should be hard limit, but I'm wondering if sigmoid can also be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To exploit their full power, neural networks require continuous, differentable activation functions. Thresholding is not a good choice for multilayer neural networks. Sigmoid is quite generic function, which can be applied in most of the cases. When you are doing a binary classification (`0/1` values), the most common approach is to define **one** output neuron, and simply choose a class 1 iff its output is bigger than a threshold (typically 0.5).

**EDIT**

As you are working with quite simple data (two input dimensions and two output classes) it seems a best option to actually abandon neural networks and start with data visualization. 2d data can be simply plotted on the plane (with different colors for different classes). Once you do it, you can investigate  how hard is it to separate one class from another. If data is located in the way, that you can simply put a line separating them - linear support vector machine would be much better choice (as it will guarantee one global optimum). If data seems really complex, and the decision boundary has to be some curve (or even set of curves) I would suggest going for RBF SVM, or at least regularized form of neural network (so its training is at least quite repeatable). If you decide on neural network - situation is quite similar - if data is simply to separate on the plane - you can use simple (linear/threshold) activation functions. If it is not linearly separable - use sigmoid or hyperbolic tangent which will ensure non linearity in the decision boundary.

**UPDATE**

Many things changed through last two years. In particular (as suggested in the comment, @Ulysee) there is a growing interest in functions differentable "almost everywhere" such as [ReLU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_%28neural_networks%29). These functions have valid derivative in most of its domain, so the probability that we will ever need to derivate in these point is zero. Consequently, we can still use classical methods and for sake of completness put a zero derivative if we need to compute `ReLU'(0)`. There are also fully differentiable approximations of ReLU, such as softplus function

Comment: Well I'm not actually building the network, but just researching on it for an assignment. The input will be the frequency and amplitude obtained by pre-processing the input signal using an auditory model and adaptive oscillators (partial tracking)
Time delay neural network, a multilayer feedforward network seems to be the best option with one hidden layer with supervised learning.

Comment: Also since i use a threshold value, then my output is between the range of 0 and 1. I found this definition for sigmoid function "This function is especially advantageous for use in neural networks trained by back-propagation, because it is easy to differentiate, and thus can dramatically reduce the computation burden for training. It applies to applications whose desired output values are between 0 and 1.  "

Comment: I think I get an idea now. Thank you.

Comment: If you're doing binary classification, you should have *one* output neuron, since the response from that neuron is sufficient to code class. Also, a point of clarification, but neural nets are non-linear only if they use a non-linear activation function *and* include a hidden layer. On such a simple problem I'd be tempted to go with logistic regression first, which is equivalent to a single output node, two layer neural net with sigmoid activation trained to minimise cross entropy loss.

Comment: This is an old answer, but please note that 1) a differentiable activation function is NOT necessary. In fact RELU units, which are piecewise linear, are extremely powerful and lead to much faster convergence, and 2) sigmoid units are awful. At the very least, use tanh units, but any kind of saturating unit (zero gradients in large regions) require careful tuning of inputs & initialization of weights, which is highly problem-dependent and time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article has some useful "soft" continuous threshold functions - see Figure Gjl-t(x).svg.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function.

Following Occam's Razor, the simpler model using one output node is a good starting point for binary classification, where one class label is mapped to the output node when activated, and the other class label for when the output node is not activated.